# Remote debug Idea doesn't works for openresty

Tags: intellij-idea, lua, remote-debugging, openresty

I am using mobDebug. If run a lua script from command line everything works.
But when I run them from openresty the Idea doesn't stop. It only writes "Connected/ Disconnected"
Configs:

```
  location / {
    access_by_lua_block {
      local client =  require("client")
  }
```

client.lua:

```
    local mobdebug = require("mobdebug");
    mobdebug.start()
    local lfs = require("lfs")
    print("Folder: "..lfs.currentdir())
```

modebug debug_hook is not invoked for needed lines, set_breakpoints don't invoked.

Idea Debug Logs, but nothing occures:

[image: Idea Debug Logs: Connected/Disconnected]

Idea catch debug from terminal client.lua; But it miss it from running nginx.

Answer (score 2):

THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER. It's just that I am experiencing basically the same problem, and comment space is too small to fit all the relevant observations I would like to share:

1. I was actually able to stop immediately after `mobdebug.start()` in code running in nginx, and to step-debug - but only in code called directly from `init_by_lua_block`. This code of course executes once during the server startup or config reload.
2. I was never able to stop in worker code (e.g. `rewrite_by_lua_*`). `mobdebug.coro()` didn't help, and `mobdebug.on()` threw about "attempt to yield across C-call boundary"
3. I was only ever able to stop one time, on next statement after `mobdebug.start()`; once I hit |> (Resume program), it won't stop on any further breakpoints.

Comment: i have the same problem, it cant stop on any breakpoint, just disconnect, when i remove mobdebug.done(), it can stop on the mobdebug.satrt(), but cant stop on any other breakpoint, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Using `mobdebug.loop()` is not a correct way to do this, as it's used for live coding, which is not going to work as expected with this setup. `mobdebug.start()` should be used instead.

Please see an example of how this debugging can be setup with ZeroBrane Studio here: http://notebook.kulchenko.com/zerobrane/debugging-openresty-nginx-lua-scripts-with-zerobrane-studio. All the details to how paths to mobdebug and required modules are configured should still be applicable to your environment.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried start, but it doesn't worked(

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? It shouldn't be doing more "connected/disconnected" looping, so the debugging should start for sure.

Comment: It writes: "Can't start debugging for '/Users/igracheva/IdeaProjects/smart-hub/smart-hub/nginx/lua/test_debug.lua'. Compilation error:"